# calling php page in a div onclick a button using ajax calls

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am using ajax script to call a php page `"MAINPAGE.PHP"` by clicking on a button , that page contains an echo statement into a div whose id is `"YOURDIV"` but its not calling the `"MAINPAGE.PHP"` see the code below and directly run this on your `localhost`:

**NEW UPDATE :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script>







function yourFunction($x)//passed $url as $x as you said 
{

var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "mainpage.php";// url to where to send
var params = "url=<?php echo $x;?>"; // here we add the php var $url as an 'url' request         parameter
xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);

//Send the proper header information along with the request
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);// add the length into header
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
alert(xmlhttp.responseText); // or do some other stuff
}
}
xmlhttp.send(params);// requesting with parameters. params contains value of url 

var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xmlhttp.open("POST","mainpage.php",true);
xmlhttp.send();

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{

 $('.container').html(xmlhttp.responseText);
}
}


}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<!--this is the main form,if we press submit button four divs are formed , basically designing         part-->
<form method="POST" action="#">
<input type="text" name="search"><input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{ 
$button = $_POST ['submit'];
$search = $_POST ['search'];
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");//connecting from database
if(!$con)
{
die("error:".mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("database",$con);
$query="SELECT * FROM tablename ";
$result=mysql_query($query);//tablename contains two fields of four records: 1-S.no, 2- URL like     www.google.com, yahoo, bing,rediff

while($runrows = mysql_fetch_assoc($results))// runrows is array with all the table content
{
$url = $runrows ['URL']; //$url now contains url from the database
echo"<div class='main' style='position:relative;border:1px solid #A5BEBE;background-        color:#E7EFEF;width:84%;  '> 
<b> sometext:-</b><a href='#'>$url</a><br>
</p>
<!-- passed $url in yourfunction as you said-->
<input type='submit' value='expand' class='myButton'  name='button1'     onclick='yourFunction($url);'            style='position:absolute;left:85%;top:4%;background:#B20000;color:white;width:70px;height:20px;font-            size:15px;' >";
echo "<div  class='container' id='yourdiv' style='background:white; '></p>";
echo "</div>";
echo "</div>";
}
mysql_close($con);
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

**heres how i am using $url in mainpage.php**

```
<?php
echo 'the response is ', $_POST['url'];//here i want the value of $url for further working
$z=array("google","yahoo","bing","rediff");
for($i=0;$i<=3;$i++){
if (ereg(".*($z[$i]).*", $url))
{
switch($i)
{
case 0:
$a=fopen($url,"r");//opening google site
echo "you have entered"$a;//you have entered www.google.com
break;

case 1:
$a=fopen($url,"r");
echo "you have entered"$a;
break;

case 2:
$a=fopen($url,"r");
echo "you have entered"$a;
break;

case 3:
$a=fopen($url,"r");
echo "you have entered"$a;
break;    
}
}
}
?>
```

when you run above code you'll see four divs with four buttons on it, So  whenever i press on anyone of four buttons that mainpage.php must echo message into required div but its not . please suggest anyone what should i do .

Thanx in advance.
  @igor if you dont understand anything i'll explain it to you .i've sent you this just for understanding the concept its lengthy but easy to understand .

**Update1:**

1.- I've tried this code in rough for passing $url and its working ::

```
<script>
function sendValue(id){
window.location='edit.php?ID=' + id;
}
</script>
<?php $url="hello";?>
<form method="POST" action="#">    
<input type="button" onclick="javascript:sendValue('<?php echo $url; ?>')>
</form>
```

but my whole code is in php so, I tried this which is not working  ::

```
<script>
function sendValue(id){
window.location='mainpage.php?ID=' + id;
}
</script>
<?php
$url="jhdbvkjsbd";
echo '<form method="POST" action="#">
<input type="button" onclick="javascript:sendValue($url);">
</form>';
?>
```

So kindly explain how to pass $url in right way but should be in php.

**2.-** secondly in mainpage.php the switch cases , ereg function and  $a=fopen($url,"r"); was working well when i directly load this mainpage.php in while loop by including it in php instead of loading it after clicking on button one by one see the code below :

```
while($runrows = mysql_fetch_assoc($results))// runrows is array with all the table content
{
$url = $runrows ['URL']; //$url now contains url from the database
echo"<div class='main' style='position:relative;border:1px solid #A5BEBE;background-        color:#E7EFEF;width:84%;  '> 
<b> sometext:-</b><a href='#'>$url</a><br>
</p>
<!-- passed $url in yourfunction as you said-->
<input type='submit' value='expand' class='myButton'  name='button1'     onclick='yourFunction($url);'            style='position:absolute;left:85%;top:4%;background:#B20000;color:white;width:70px;height:20px;font-            size:15px;' >";
echo "<div  class='container' id='yourdiv' style='background:white; '></p>";

include('mainpage.php'); //this statement directly loads mainpage.php and shows data in this div but i want the data to be shown after clicking the button

echo "</div>";
echo "</div>";
}
mysql_close($con);
}
```

if you can access this $url variable in mainpage.php then hopefully it works.

**UPDATE LATEST:**

```
function showRSS(str) 
{

$('#loading').html('<img src="Preloader_1.gif"> loading...');


var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "mainpage.php?q=+str";// url to where to send
var params = "url="; // here we add the php var $url as an 'url' request parameter
xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);

//Send the proper header information along with the request
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);// add the length into header
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
    alert(xmlhttp.responseText); 
  }
}
xmlhttp.send(params);

var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {
    // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

  xmlhttp.open("POST","mainpage.php?q="+str,true);
  xmlhttp.send();

  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
  {
     $('.container').html(xmlhttp.responseText);
  }
}

}
```

and i want to show that loading image in main div with class="main" till the contents are loading in container div and as they loaded once that image should automatically fadeout please tell me where am i doing wrong

```
echo"<div class='main' style='position:relative;border:1px solid #A5BEBE;background-color:#E7EFEF;width:84%;'><div id='loading'>

</div> 
<b> sometext:-</b><a href='#'>$url</a><br>
</p>
<!-- passed $url in yourfunction as you said-->
<input type='submit' value='expand' class='myButton' name='button1' onclick='yourFunction($url);'style='position:absolute;left:85%;top:4%;background:#B20000;color:white;width:70px;height:20px;font-            size:15px;' >";
echo "<div  class='container' id='yourdiv' style='background:white; '></p>";
echo "</div>";
echo "</div>";


<style>
#loading {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
position: fixed;
display: block;
opacity: 0.8;
background-color: #000;
z-index: 99;
text-align: center;
}
#loading-image {
position: absolute;
top: 40%;
left: 45%;
z-index: 100;
}
</style>
```

Comment: `id` is always unique and when in `for loop` it actually doesnt be like.

Comment: yeah i forgot , then should i use class instead of id , is it possible i.e. document.getElementByclass("container").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

Comment: If you're going to use jQuery, stick to jQuery. JQuery supports Ajax which handles all of the crossbrowser stuff for you. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: that jquery is used only for designing matter but for the button i am using ajax calls.Please explain if i use class instead of id will it be ok?

Comment: you shouldn't have duplicate IDs, so in that sense, yes.

Comment: @Darkknight, for your buttons you define `type='submit'` not `type='button'`

Comment: @ igor i've used submit also but it is still not working . Kindly help

Comment: @Darkknight, see my 4th update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is it possible i.e. document.getElementByclass("container").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText

It is, do it:

```
$('.container').html(xmlhttp.responseText);
```

By the way **you do not check for the `xmlhttp` status code**, cause only if status code = 200 and readyState=4 the responce is present back from server. But you check it right away.

From [here](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_onreadystatechange.asp):

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
  {
      document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
  }
}
```

### Update

> in for loop i am using a $url variable which contains the url and this same $url is also present in mainpage.php . so through this $url their are some more further echo statements executing in maipage.php . can you tell me why this $url is not working in mainpage.php

In your original php file you want to manage certain $url passing it into mainpage.php. You can do it as the data of ajax request.

```
<?php $url='smth'; ?>

var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "mainpage.php";// url to where to send
var params = "url=<?php echo $url;?>"; // here we add the php var $url as an 'url' request parameter
xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);

//Send the proper header information along with the request
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);// add the length into header
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
  if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
    alert(xmlhttp.responseText); // or do some other stuff
  }
}
xmlhttp.send(params);// requesting with parameters.
```

In **mainpage.php** you address the passed POST parameter 'url' as:

```
$_POST['url']
```

### Update 2

In the `for` loop you've defined the target divs:

```
 echo "<div  class='container' id='yourdiv' style='display:none;background:white; '>";
```

- get rid of ununiqueness if div:  `id='yourdiv{$i}'`
- remove `style='display:none;`, rather leave `div` empty, it'll shrink into dot.

now you refer to them as `#yourdiv1` or `#yourdiv2` etc.

```
echo "<div class='container' id='yourdiv{$i}'></div>";
```

### Update 3

I've composed for you a [test case](http://tarex.ru/testdir/test5.php)
But to insert the response into the corrsponding `div` will take you more effort...

### Update 4

1. On the `input` click the `yourFunction()` works, but there no `url` parameter passed into it.
2. The code with xhr (that i've given to you) works on page load/ready; it rather should be invoked in function with $url properly passed into it from button. Assign buttons unique ids and pass them in the `yourFunction()`, then pass them in xhr.
3. `ereg(".*($z[$i]).*", $url)` is outdated, better to use `preg_match()`, but not nessesary.
4. the variable `$url` is NOT defined in mainpage.php (ex. `$a=fopen($url,"r");`), rather use $_POST['url']: `$a=fopen($_POST['url'],"r");`
5. What is `$b`?
6. Please, show your code with proper **indentation**, this shows your coding attitude and influences readers.
7. You might remove the old code from your question leaving only the code you presently have and write in commenta what works and what does not work.

### Update 5

- You do right passing $url into yourFunction() and then thru xhr into mainpage.php.
- But inside mainpage.php you echo twice: `echo 'the response is ', $_POST['url']` and at one of switch cases: `echo "you have entered"$a;`
- If you have had mainpage.php echoing `'the response is ', $_POST['url']` then it properly returns on xhr. But when you add switch cases with ereg() and now have no response - then there is error somewhere in this code.
- `$a=fopen($url,"r");` is not the best solution for getting content by url (are you going to close it?). You'd rather use `cUrl` library or `file_get_contents()` for that purpose.

### Update 6

This is not working:

```
$url="jhdbvkjsbd";
echo '<form method="POST" action="#">
<input type="button" onclick="javascript:sendValue($url);">
</form>';
```

because in echo you use `'` rather then `"` and within `'` the variable is not eveluated. Try this within echo:

```
echo '<form method="POST" action="#">
<input type="button" onclick="javascript:sendValue('.$url.' );">
</form>';
```

> include('mainpage.php'); //this statement directly loads mainpage.php and shows data in this div but i want the data to be shown after clicking the button

If you want to go this way then you might first hide date from/in mainpage.php by wrapping them with div with some class and id:

.some-class{ dispaly:none; }

Then on button click you remove that class from selected id and data will be visible.

### Update 7

> Can we add a loading image in this till the contents are loading?

Since xhr is **an asynchronous process** you can't know when it starts and finishes. The function `onreadystatechange` checks the events to happen. The function `open` opens the process. So you just wrap the logic with them:

```
// here the ajax call is initiated, made open
xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);
// so down here you might insert JS code to put image on screen
...
// this function checks if response is ready "readyState == 4" so inside you might set a code to remove image
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() { 
   if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
     <remove image code...>
     alert(xmlhttp.responseText); // or do some other stuff
   }
}
```

Comment: Great work mr. Igor Savinkin , but their's one more problem that in for loop i am using  a $url variable which contains the url and this same $url  is also present in mainpage.php . so through this $url their are some more further echo statements executing in maipage.php . can you tell me why this $url is not working in    mainpage.php  please  it will be of great help if you solve this one

Comment: okay i've added your script in my previous script above the function ""function yourFunction()"" and added ""$_POST['url']"" in mainpage.php  as it is and this style=display none is for hiding divs container by default ,, if i remove this the divs are already shown without this icant hide them bydefault

Comment: @Darkknight, now you return this `$_POST['url']` as response text in mainpage.php:
<?php echo 'the response is ', $_POST['url']; ?> and see thru debug tools (F12) the response.

Comment: hey i got the problem its showing "smth" which is the value of $url   given in <?php $url='smth'; ?> but i am already having its values in for loop . actually i dint show that in coding but i am getting all values of $url from a database connectivity and use that url in mainpage.php by calling it from the button so this $url get values from database using for loop and i want them to be passed in mainpage.php for further operations....may be now you get the proper concept

Comment: i know its not easy but its really important for my project your efforts wouldn't get wasted .If i removed your "<?php $url='smth'; ?>" i get this only "the response is" instead of "the response is smth" so in place of this smth how can i get the url text from my database

Comment: @Darkknight, please, update your question with $url(s) showing in the `for` loop and how you are going to use them in *mainpage.php*.  What is `url text from my database`?

Comment: okay i am creating the brief code , if you dont understand i'll explain everything to you ...

Comment: i am taking the value of url from the sql database connectivity using php which is different for all the four containers, this url  value i've to pass in mainpage.php. I am doing this by $_POST['url'] but its not working. now please tell are you able to understand my question or do i've to send the code as sending the code may confuse you .

Comment: @Darkknight, code should not confuse a reader. Just simplify your code, leave only the essencial part of it and post it. Actually, cause you've only 4 urls (4 choises) you might pass only an index [0-3] thru xhr to mainpage.php; and in mainpage.php you by index and switch-case fetch urls from DB and process with selected url.

Comment: I've updated the code and done as you said @igor we've passed $url in your function but still url is not passing in maipage.php what should i do next...its really important for my project if you still dont get i'll explain everything ...

Comment: Hello mr. Igor Savinkin need your help again can we add a loading image in this till the contents are loading ..??

Comment: i think yes. In calling xhr you add an image on top thru js or css class triggering. Then in function you remove it: `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() { 
  if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
    alert(xmlhttp.responseText); // also here you remove the 'loading' image
  }
}`

Comment: ok i've added image through js and css but it shows a black screen and also doesn't show the loader image  see my UPDATE LATEST :

Comment: Hey @igor its playing the reverse action as i click on button it doesn't show the image and contents are loaded after some time but as i click again to close divs it shows the image loading where contents are not required to be shown.

Comment: @Darkknight, it's hard for me to find out your problem, since i'm not that well in css. Seems to me problem is that you put loading image in php (making it fixed html), while **xhr is done in real time thru js**. Both putting image and removing need to be done in js. So try to google: 'js set or remove image' to find examples. Why not using two classes `.loading-on` and `.loading-off` and toggle them in js: `$(<selector>).removeClass(<...>).addClass(<...>)`

Comment: similarly i am new to xhr , ajax requests and all but there is something you can tell me a little about how this ajax works i mean i just want to add loader when the process of fetching data just atarts and remove that image when processing ends . But i am not getting when this processing starts and ends ..???

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure I understood your question fully, but here's a bit of clean-up. Note: untested. Few additional questions: why are you treating the showing and hiding differently for `buttons.parent()`, can you detail exactly what you want?

```
$(function(){
  var $btns = $('.myButton'),
      $moms = $btns.parent();

  $('body').on('click', '.myButton', function(e) {
    var $ct = $(this).next("div.container"),
        isCollapsed = this.value == 'expand';
        this.value = isCollapsed ? 'expand' : 'collapse';
        $ct[isCollapsed ? 'show':'hide']('slow');

        // sorry got lazy here
        // also, why are you treating the conditions differently, not oppositely?
        if (isCollapsed)
          $moms.show('slow');
        else
          $btns.not($(this)).parent().hide('slow');

        // if this is the button you want to send ajax call
        $.post('mainpage.php', function(data) {
          $('.container').html(data);
        });
  });
});
```